First layer printing too high, why am I unable to determine the reason?
I have been using this printer for years, random CoreXY kit, 8-bit Melzi board, generic MK8-style bowden hotend, heated bed, driven by Marlin 1.1.9 with Unified bed leveling enabled.
Last print several weeks ago was fine, did not at all adjust the hardware, but now it's air-printing the first layer. Redid the leveling (manual 16-point mesh spaced using a 0.15mm depth gauge) and there was no improvement. Thought I might have messed up something in Cura's gcode preamble section, so I printed an older file that worked fine previously, same problem. Display shows 0.24 mm height when first layer starts, which matches Cura's settings (though I'm not sure if that should change when bed level is on?). Changing "Bed Z" setting appears to have no effect, but I don't think I've used it since turning on bed leveling. The Z endstop adjustment is fine and will happily let the nozzle dig into the bed if requested.
If I run the leveling routine, I feel like it should negate any other factors since it knows where the bed is "now". So what the heck am I missing here that is throwing it off?

Could you define too high? Is it mm's or tenths of mm's? Has your nozzle been shortened by wear? When redoing the leveling (I assume you have some sort of a sensor, or do you use UBL, since you mentioned Z endstop adjustment), did you also do the paper method to determine the Z-offset?

Added some details to the original question, but I'm creating the mesh with a steel leaf from a set of depth gauges instead of paper. Z offset is called Bed Z on this release I believe - but as mentioned it didn't seem to affect anything when altered.
I started the printer up again in order to measure the actual distance (knew that I should have already), and it's now working fine.

How are you tramming your bed? Do you heat your bed first or are you doing it while cold?

Come back the next day and everything will be fine. It's an unfulfilling answer, but I plan to upgrade this to a better control board very soon so I'll take it.
